# Why does my PHP segfault on implicit __toString()?

Tags: php, string, segmentation-fault

Suddenly this morning, a PHP server stopped serving some webpages. I didn't change anything, but maybe automated updates did. The PHP instances segfaulted, and Apache returned a blank page. I've traced the problem to this:

```
array_unique( $arr ); # segfault
```

which uses the string representation of the objects in `$arr`. This also makes the program segfault:

```
echo $arr[0]; # segfault
```

But this does not!

```
echo $arr[0]->__toString(); # works as expected
```

This does segfault:

```
echo (string)$arr[0]; # segfault
```

I thought that the last three lines would be identical.

What could be wrong? I'll try to write a MWE but I figured maybe someone had seen this before and had any ideas.

```
function __toString() {
    return 'Product #' . $this->id;
}
```

Comment: is the container(array) relevant or you can reproduce the problem with an object?

Comment: You may want to [ask Apache for a core dump, then break out the debugging tools](http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/).